# How to create multiple addresses using netplan in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: netplan

How to create multiple addresses using netplan in Ubuntu 18.04? I want to assign 50 addresses using notation like `192.10.23.1/24-192.10.23.50/24`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible.

[Here](https://netplan.io/examples) you can file lots of examples on how to configure `netplan` for various use cases. For your specific needs it should be as simple as

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets: 
    enp3s0:                     # Use your interface name
     addresses:
       - 192.10.23.1/24
       - 192.10.23.2/24
       - ...                    # fill all 50 addresses
       - 192.10.23.50/24
     gateway4: 192.10.23.254/24 # use your gateway, or none if it's not needed
```

I've used [this](https://netplan.io/examples#multiple-addresses-on-an-interface) as a reference.

Don't forget to do a `sudo netplan apply` to commit your changes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any range option in netplan configuration. What I can only suggest is to use script, for example in Bash to generate your range:

```
gen.sh:
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..50}
do
echo "    - 192.10.23.$i/24" # <-- watch for spaces :)
done
```

Then:

```
$ bash gen.sh > config.yml
```

Add some header / footer and you're done
Cheers, Paweł